# Swap Buffers and Clear Back using windowing system (GLX)

Tags: c++, x11, xlib, egl, glx

When swapping between back and front buffers the content in the back buffer becomes undefined. I´d like to define it using the "windowing system", such as GLX, EGL, WGL. Using "native" renderer such as OpenGL (glClear) is my backup plan, don´t bother mentioning it. The reason it is backup is because I don´t want to mess with native rendering contexts. I´ll stick to X/GLX for this question but if you feel inclined to describe how to do it in other Environments then go ahead.

From the Xlib documentation (http://www.x.org/docs/X11/xlib.pdf) I find an operation, XClearWindow, for clearing window with "background pixel" (awesome name by the way... not).

1. Does XClearWindow clear front/back or both buffers? I guess back buffer makes sense but I can´t figure it out from Xlib documents alone... And if anyone asked about triple buffers, it wasn´t me!
2. Is it synchronous to OpenGL rendering, or do I have to synchronize myself by for example calling glxWaitGL before the operation?
3. Is the command blocking, ie halts until complete? Implementation dependent?

Other suggestions as how to clear the back buffer after a swap using windowing system (GLX) is appriciated.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

> When swapping between back and front buffers the content in the back buffer becomes undefined.

Yes, and that is a good thing.

> I´d like to define it using the "windowing system", such as GLX, EGL, WGL

Why? Apart from that doing this is just as undefined, as the background after a swap nothing good will come from it.

At best it will just degrade performance if the OpenGL DDX is aware of the XClearWindow it will sync. At worst you're introducing a race condition between which the results are unpredicatable.

> Other suggestions as how to clear the back buffer after a swap using windowing system (GLX) is appriciated.

Use the proper OpenGL operation: `glClear(…)`.

Comment: If i define the content after a swap it is by definition defined because I just defined it. Because windowing system swap does not degrade performance, it is reasonable to believe (but not proven) that windowing system clear does not degrade performance. And OpenGL is not a windowing system. Using glClear is known backup plan and I explicitly asked you not to bother mentioning it. As for my grand scheme in which this piece of the puzzle will guarantee world domination you should not bother. Just tell me what you know about windowing system synchronization with OpenGL.

Comment: @Andreas I can define `*NULL` to result in the value `0xDEADBEEF`, but that's completely useless if the implementation does not respect that definition. What makes you think that the window system's clear is more performant than your OpenGL implementation's `glClear`? Your question smells like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Andreas: You hardly will get any more performant than `glClear`. XClearWindow may actually perform a complex fill operation (fill the window with the defined background tile). Also the main implementation of XClearWindow will likely be implemented as a CPU driven memory write to GPU memory. It may or may not be DMA assisted, but it's never going to be as fast as a single command to the GPU *marking* a whole region of memory being set to a particular value. Note that I wrote *"marking"*:

Comment: @Andreas: Most modern GPUs are in fact just setting a flag per memory block to assume it to have a uniform value. Also in GLX direct rendering mode OpenGL commands completely bypass the X server. Furthermore XClearWindow may create an `Exposed` event, and the contents of a window's back buffer are *undefined* after being `Expose`-ed, so this just leaves you where you started.

Comment: @Andreas: I wonder why you're specifically asking about `glClear`. I have a suspicion though: Could it be, that you timed how long it takes for `glClear` to execute, that you measured it on a system with an Intel GPU and that you arrived at a figure of about one display refresh period worth (about 16.666ms for a 60Hz display)? If that's the case, what you actually observed is, that the Mesa/Intel driver has glXSwapBuffers returning immediately; the very next non-queable OpenGL operation that modifies the back buffer thereafter will then be delayed until the buffer swap actually happened.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo And my reasons are not to magically increase performance, it is to reduce responabilities (thread and context consideration) which are out of scope for a part of my architectural component. I basically wish to decouple my window managing from overly competent and complex 3D rendering capabilities. AND reading Xlib/GLX/OpenGL standards, this seems to be possible and so I reach out to people with more experience of it. Should probably un-tag OpenGL as it is more of a Xlib question...

Comment: @datenwolf I'd rather not use glClear because it require context management. I'll look into what exposed events are and get back to you. Feels like we are getting somewhere. As for your claims for how XClearWindow is implemented I would like some reference. Where do you get this information?

Comment: @datenwolf Imagine your OpenGL rendering covering a series of region on the display, and you cannot guarantee that the region will together cover the whole framebuffer. Where no regions cover the pixels are undefined, smart GPU flag bit or not. Are you sure GPU do this flagging? Where did you learn that? BACKUP plan is to have a region covering the whole framebuffer. So don't you worry about my application, just interpret the standards for me.

Comment: @Andreas: If it's not about performance, then its moot. Clearing the framebuffer is part of the drawing process, not part of window management (just like setting the viewport and scissor rectangle should be done during drawing and not in window resize handler). Also the moment framebuffer objects are used, the 3D parts requires OpenGL clearing again.

Comment: @Andreas: You're mentioning threads. So are you trying to draw to the same drawable using multiple OpenGL contexts from multiple threads at the same time? If you do so, then the whole thing invokes undefined behaviour: Because writes to the framebuffer are not atomic, it may happen that colour writes happen before depth buffer writes, and as such will race the depth test. If you want to do multithreaded rendering to the same target (which opens a huge can of worms), the most stable method is to use a own FBO for each thread and to compose those into to the main framebuffer.

Comment: @datenwolf Leave the tradeoff considerations between performance and system decoupling to me. The final product is safety critical (nuclear, aerospace, medical). Hardware cost is 10% of the product, verification and maintenance is 90%. Mainly because expected lifetime of my product is between 10-30 years. Clearing the framebuffer is not necessarily part of the (3D) rendering process, although often being implemented that way.

Comment: @datenwolf Writes to framebuffer need not be atomic if the regions rendered do not overlap. Those who do overlap have to be syncronized (glxWaitGL or similar). Your technique, although most useful in many cases, has a few flaws. Extra copy operation from FBO to framebuffer is one of them which you performance junkies may care about. The other is that you cannot do this if any of the regions run code without FBO support (Legacy OpenGL, OpenGL ES 1.1). And I just so happen to have such legacy code that I do not wish to port. Window manager tricks should be much more lean.

Comment: @Andreas: If you're targeting high reliability then you absolutely never must do anything that relies on undefined or undocumented behaviour. And right now, you're deep in undocumented, unspecified, undefined behaviour territory. Good like finding an auditor worth his money who's going to rubber stamp that. Just FYI, I'm doing medical grade software development at the company I co-founded; if anyone working for me suggested to implement things as you suggested in out high-rel software I'd immediately pull him or her from the project. When it comes to high-rel **KISS** is king.

Comment: @datenwolf I totally agree about how to achieve a high reliability! And my question is and has always been about how I may define the back buffer content after swap on a proper level of abstraction, ie window abstraction. We simply disagree on what "simple" is. I say it is "use the right tools for the right job". What I hear from you is more like "use tools we know work, then make them do the job". Subtle difference. And a little of both is probably the best depending on situation. But I shouldn´t really put words in your mouth. That´s just what I´m hearing. Oh, and this is off the clock btw.

Answer (score 0):

After some research I may have found a solution. The documents seem to be in order but I have not had the chance of testing this in practice. I´ll update the answer with code once I got something working.

> Does XClearWindow clear front/back or both buffers?

X does not have the concept of double buffers. Whenever interacting with X against a double buffered window, both buffers are affected. The exception being reading operations such as `XGetImage` that only operate on the front buffer.

X is however extended with a double buffer concept through the X Double Buffer Extension, or xdbe: http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/xextproto/dbe.html#dbeswapbuffers

xdbe provide the `XdbeSwapBuffers` operation similar to `glxSwapBuffers` provided by GLX. There are some important differences:

- XdbeSwapBuffers does not manage any synchronization with any client
     API like glxSwapBuffers do. The user has to do this manually. Luckily, GLX provide great
     synchronization operations (`glxWaitGL` and `glxWaitX`) that won´t stall
     execution. That pretty much answers my second question.
- glxSwapBuffers performs an implicit flush (`glFlush`) for the current
  context. XdbeSwapBuffers does not. When to flush or not is an
  application designer decision.
- XdbeSwapBuffers may swap many windows    in one call.
- XdbeSwapBuffers    may have different behavior when    swapping:
  'Undefined',    'Background', 'Untouched', 'Copied'. Read the    link
  for details.

For clearing after a swap to a predefined color the 'Background' swap behavior is the way to go. What to clear to can be configured through X and may be a pixmap or single color (background pixel).

> Is the command blocking, ie halts until complete? Implementation
>   dependent?

An application using X have to provide its own synchronization mechanisms in many situations. This would indicate an asynchronous execution pattern, but the standard itself does not require it. I´d go with "implementation defined" with a strong suggestion that most commands for most platforms are asynchronously executed.