# Unity windows manager - frame synchronization for openGL applications

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, opengl

I'm trying to receive `_NET_WM_SYNC_REQUEST` events to have [frame synchronization](http://fishsoup.net/misc/wm-spec-synchronization.html) in openGL applications.

Everything works great in gnome but the same applications can't receive the

```
case ClientMessage: {

  if ((Atom)event->xclient.data.l[0] == ATOM(_NET_WM_SYNC_REQUEST)) 
  {
     .. handle ..
  }
} break;
```

so my question is: does Unity windows manager features frame synchronization at all and/or has some sort of replacement for it?

Comment: I tried to find a "documentation" or similar for Unity. No luck so far. Do you have any other reference than the frame synchronization link I might peek into?

Comment: @Andreas unfortunately not. I really don't know what to do.. every piece of code I wrote or found works in gnome, it doesn't in unity

Comment: Ok. I'd ask the Unity devs directly in that case. Good luck. I'm on an adventure myself in the xlib wonder world: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36336563/swap-buffers-and-clear-back-using-windowing-system-glx I'll tell you if I find something interesting.

Comment: @Andreas Thanks! I appreciate your help! I'll do the same if I find out something. For now, everything goes in the direction of "unity needs some fixing for the sync frame messages"